# java array with vertices of dodecahedron

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an array of arrays

```
int x[][] = new int[20][3];
```

where the indexes of x are the vertices of a dodecahedron(just labeled 0-19 since the dodecahedron has 20 vertices), and the elements of x[0-19] are the neighbor vertices.
If this is not clear take this sample:

```
    int y[][] = {{ 1,  5,  4}, { 0,  7,  2}, { 1,  9,  3}, { 2, 11,  4},
                 { 3, 13,  0}, { 0, 14,  6}, { 5, 16,  7}, { 1,  6,  8},
                 { 7,  9, 17}, { 2,  8, 10}, { 9, 11, 18}, {10,  3, 12},
                 {19, 11, 13}, {14, 12,  4}, {13,  5, 15}, {14, 19, 16},
                 { 6, 15, 17}, {16,  8, 18}, {10, 17, 19}, {12, 15, 18}};
```

In this sample array `y[0][0-2]` refers to the neighbors of vertex 0, which happen to be 1,5, and 4. In line with this, `y[1]`, `y[5]`, and `y[6]` contain 0.

I dont want to just write in this array, rather I want to create a random version of this.

Comment: What's wrong with the sample in your question?

Comment: You should clarify, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @RC and @Keith Randall I just updated what i want to get

Comment: But if you pick random neighbours for the nodes, you won't have a dodecahedron ...

Comment: @Stephen C I dont mean totally random, I meant more like shuffle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to renumber the vertices in a "random" fashion while preserving the dodecahedron vertex structure, then this should do the trick:

```
    int[] shuffle = // an array containing a permutation of [0..19]
    int[][] z = new int[20][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int[] vy = y[i];
        int[] vz = new int[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            vz[j] = shuffle[vy[j]];
        }
        z[shuffle[i]] = vz;
    }
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) -- <19 ? should it be <20?

Answer (score 0):

Create the initial one, like you did, and then start shuffleing it.
(lets call it int[][]x -- because you named it it x and y)

Select two different edges by random and swap them, repeat this several times.

If to swap two edges, you have to swap the arrays, as well as the "references" in the arrays.
for example: swap edge 1 and 10:
psydo code:

```
int[] temp = x[1];
x[1] = x[10];
x[10] = temp;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    if (x[i][k]==1) {
       x[i][k]= 10;
    } else if(x[i][k]==10) {
       x[i][k]= 1;
    }
  }
}
```